# How can I convert a String of ASCII codes back to the values they represent in Java

Tags: java, regex, split, ascii

Given a numeric string consisting of several characters' *ASCII* representations concatenated together, I'd like to parse it back into the original value/s.  For example, if I had the input:

```java
String input = "495051108";
```

The string could be divided into the values `49`, `50`, `51` & `108`. Which when converted into their character equivalent, would result in the output `"123l"`.

I believe the best way to do this is with a regular expression because of the ease of splitting strings and my requirement to *"look-ahead"* as to whether the next character begins with a `1` (in order to determine how many characters I should be looking at next in the sequence).

What would be the best way to express this?

Comment: The thing is that it might be difficult to differentiate between "1", "12", and "123". Or "4" and "49". Or "9" and "95". You get my point.

Comment: This makes too many assumptions in terms of ambiguous parsing. Have you also tried anything yourself?

Comment: It's definitely possible, I have managed it before using regex. It uses the look-ahead function if I can remember

Comment: If you've managed it before then why are you asking here? And how would your regex decide what ASCII character to use when there are several options? Look-ahead only tells you if you're going to end up with an invalid ASCII code, not whether the resulting string makes any sense

Comment: Because I can't remember and I don't have my old code to do it. If the ascii character starts with 1, it takes the next two digits, and if it doesn't, it takes one. It would have to jump two places to check if the 1 is followed by another 1 and so on.

Comment: That sounds like an extremely simple and accurate algorithm. What's the problem? :) The "lookahead" part of it would be fairly basic to implement. Maybe an "extraction" function that returns the end-index (next index to check - 1). If you really want a regex, experiment some.

Comment: I suppose that would work as long as your string is guaranteed not to have anything less than 20...

Comment: Whatever is producing this as output is really the only thing that needs fixing...

Answer (score 1):

Given that the first 33 characters in the *ASCII* table are control characters (non-printable) and anything in the English language can probably be expressed within the first 128 character range - this seems feasible if you know where the input is coming from, ***i.e.*** you can impose some constraints.

This is a simple algorithm based on your description, it chunks the input 2 or 3 characters at a time until it's length is reduced to zero - I'll leave it up to yourself to add any validation / error handling...

```java
public String fromAscii(String str) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(str.length()>0){
        int len = str.startsWith("1") ? 3 : 2;
        sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, len)));
        str = str.substring(len);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/FXSPxo)

Comment: ... and just in case it wasn't obvious - you don't need a regex for this :)

Comment: Although one other thing you should do is use a `StringBuilder` rather than a `String`...